# background sizing in css bindings?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain to me what is going on with this property. Its a css background img the scales down to half size for retina pixel display density.

```
background: url('../img/kellin-retina.png') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px /200px 70px;
```

What is up with the **0px 0px** part before the **/200px 70px**. If i take it out the background doesn't scale down. what are these two pixel sizes binding to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first set `0px 0px` defines the position of the background image (top left), the second set `200px 70px` defines the dimensions, in this short-hand notation it represents [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

If you only have one value in the second set, it will be the width of the image. To just set the height, you can do something like:

```
background: url('../img/kellin-retina.png') no-repeat scroll 0px 0px /auto 70px;
```

The background will then be 70px high and the width will be scaled accordingly. See a [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/u66b6du4/), where the background image will always be half as high as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of what you're stating, consider including all the properties like this:

```
background-image: url('../img/kellin-retina.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-size: 200px 70px;
```

This is your code broken down to what it means. I don't exactly what your problem is, but try opening your browser's Dev Tools to uncheck and check the properties to see what effect it has on your page, and modify the numbers to better understand what you're doing. If you need help in making something specific work, I can help if you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code or show me the live site.